# RenderScript allocation to OpenGL ES 2.0 vertex buffer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, renderscript, vertex-buffer

In RenderScript I'm creating a fixed-length array of vertices, which I'm drawing using OpenGL ES 2.0.

Currently I'm copying the output allocation to a float array, converting this array to a bytebuffer and sending this bytebuffer to OpenGL. Is there any more efficient way of doing this? For instance by creating a bytebuffer from the RenderScript allocation directly?

Comment: There's no possibility for such operation. In my case I was able to implement a workaround by performing computation in vertex shader instead of RS code. Alternatively, you can use transform feedback feature of OpenGL ES 3.0.